# Rails ActiveRelation - chaining where conditions as OR, not AND, using scope's and .merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm familiar that you can do something like

```
.where('guests.name ILIKE ?', "%#{term}%").where('orders.number = ?', term)
```

And that generates an "AND" query, matching both the guests.name and orders.number.

I want to make those OR instead of AND. Objective-C has a neat thing called NSCompoundPredicates which is what I am looking for.

I also know that I could put the .where into the same argument and specify "OR". However, I have a helper scope on my guests table, like this:

```
scope :matches_name, -> (name) { where("(guests.first_name || ' ' || guests.last_name) ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%")}
```

So naturally I'd love to use that, and chain together other OR conditions. Something like

```
Order.includes(:guest).merge(Guest.matches_name(term)).where('orders.number = ?', term)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using arel, which has an `.or` function in newer versions.

Example:

```
foos = Foo.arel_table
Foo.where(foos[:bar].eq(true).or(foos[:baz].match('%foo%')))
```